# GNU m4 installation fails on Windows 10 bash on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnu, m4, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install GNU m4 package on [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about), but always fail at configuration stage.

I wrote these:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.17.tar.gz
tar xvzf m4-1.4.17.tar.gz
cd m4-1.4.17
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/m4
```

However, the configuration process stopped at this stage:

```
checking whether rename honors trailing slash on source...
```

I had waited for more than 8 hours with no progress. I tried to restart my PC and repeated similar steps, but the trouble remains.

I found a similar question [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287238/windows10-bash-install-m4-1-4-17-stops-at-checking-whether-rename-honors-trailin) but I want to explain a bit more details about my own trouble.

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [a bug in Bash on Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1008). As a workaround, try building `m4` from a Linux directory instead of a Windows one (i.e., build it in `/home/$USER/` instead of a subdirectory of `/mnt/c`).